# Showing a finite field is a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

I am asked to find an integer $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a local ring and then to prove my answer.  Here is my attempt:

We know that $Z_p$ is a finite field for prime $p$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field, we know that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ only contains two ideals, namely $(0)$ and $(1)$.  Since $(0) \subseteq (1)$ and $(1) = \mathbb{Z}_p$, we can conclude that $(0)$ is maximal.  Finally, since $(0)$ is the only maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, we can conclude that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a local ring.

Is this correct?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Yes, all fields are local rings. But you did not answer for which $n$ the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is local. Only for $n=p$ prime ?

Comment: Yes  Also, any $\mathbf Z_{p^n}$ is a local ring which is not a field.  More generally, any  $\mathbf Z_n$ is a `semi-local` ring (i.e. it has a finite number of maximal ideals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z$ is a PID, ideal correspondence says that the ideals of $\Bbb Z/(p^n)$ are of the form $(p^k)/(p^n)$ for $0\leq k \leq n$, so such a ring is local.

Now for any $n$, we have $n=\prod p_i^{e_i}$ for finitely many distinct primes $p_i$ and nonzero exponents $e_i$.

The Chinese remainder theorem says that $\Bbb Z/(n)\cong \prod \Bbb Z/(p_i^{e_i})$. Now a product of two nonzero rings with identity is never local (why?). So $\Bbb Z/(n)$ is local iff $n=p^e$ for some prime p and positive exponent $e$.